# Why can't I log in to Minecraft? unknown username or password

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My Minecraft password will not work. I've reset it about 5 times and no matter what I choose as my password, it will not take it. I just made my Minecraft account today

I am entering my username correctly, and I am typing everything in the correct boxes, but it always says "Unknown username or password...". I know I am putting my username in correctly because if I try to re-register, it will not let me use my email because it's currently in use.

Could somebody explain to my why no matter what my Minecraft password is, it won't work?

Comment: Don't forget to check the login server status: http://help.mojang.com/ (If the servers are not operating, as does happen from time to time, you just need to wait until they are back to login.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Username and Password not recognized when logging into Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118282/username-and-password-not-recognized-when-logging-into-minecraft)

Answer (score 18):

If your account is actually a Mojang account, which I believe all new accounts are, you should actually be using the email address you signed up with in the username box.

Counter intuitive I know, but they still haven't changed it from when you actually used your username.

#### If you are already using your email address to log in

The login servers may be down. Always check [help.mojang.com](https://help.mojang.com) when you have login problems!