# Username and Password not recognized when logging into Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

We just got a new laptop (ASUS) though we did have a mac.  We are trying to log onto Mojang to download Minecraft and it keeps saying, "The username and password are not recognized."

We have done all the usual procedures; we have reset the password, we are using the email, not the username to sign in, and it looks like the minecraft login servers are working etc. etc.  We quit Minecraft on the old computer and shut off that computer thinking that was the issue.

Still, we can't get onto Mojang.  We are accessing mincraft through firefox and trying to download it to the new computer but we can't get into the account to do that!  What in the world could be the issue?

Comment: Can you log into https://account.mojang.com/?

Comment: Contact customer support?

Comment: Contact customer support or check your network setting,see if you can browse on the new pc..

Answer (score 16):

There is a number of things you should rule out first:

- Are you able to login through http://account.mojang.com/login?
- Are you using the proper client from http://minecraft.net/download?
- If you were able to login with your old computer; make sure your current one doesn't have any firewall blocking internal / external connections.
- On the computer with the issue, do the following:

  : Go to this [url](https://login.minecraft.net/?user=USER&password=PASS&version=13), and substitute `USER` for your actual username and substitute `PASS` for your actual password.

  : It should output a Session ID (a bunch of numbers and letters), if not; and it returns `Bad login` or another exception; [contact mojang](http://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new).

Comment: Holy crap, that URL works like that? That's an incredibly bad security flaw

Comment: If you do use the URL step, remember to do it in private browsing mode or clear your history afterwards so that your password is not stored in your browser history. It is in general not a good idea to send your password as part of the URL, so as an added precaution it might be a good idea to change your password after you completed the troubleshooting step

Comment: The URL to substitute is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Contact Minecraft customer support. I am using Firefox too and it works just fine, so it's not the browser; it's the UN and PW.

If it worked before on the Mac, download the WINDOWS version of Minecraft on the Mac, not the Mac version, and send yourself the downloader through email. [Download Minecraftinstaller.msi and go to your email. Attatch Minecraftinstaller.msi to the email and send it to YOURSELF.]

You can also use a different browser.

If this doesn't work, I don't even know what to say.