# How do I fix my Minecraft log-in?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I put in my email and password correctly, (trust me, I know it's correct) it says that username or password is not right. I've tried both username and email, and neither work. I've had only one password. Please help.

Comment: Did you try some form of "forgot your password?" form? Or do you no longer have access to the emailaccount?

Comment: Do the credentials work on [minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net/login)? If they work there, it's likely only a temporary problem with Minecraft's authentication servers (I believe the game uses different servers than Mojang's website).

Comment: To check if Mojang's login servers are up, check their website: help.mojang.com

Comment: they do not work on minecraft.net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Username and Password not recognized when logging into Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118282/username-and-password-not-recognized-when-logging-into-minecraft)

Answer (score 3):

If your account credentials don't work on the Minecraft.net website, then you'll need to [reset your password](https://minecraft.net/resetpassword) (or [here](https://account.mojang.com/resetpassword/request), if you have a Mojang account). If you can't do that, you will likely need to get in touch with [Minecraft Support](https://help.mojang.com/).

Answer (score -2):

I fixed it by changing my password on the minecraft website.

Comment: Next time, please expand on an answer with more details.  For instance, where on the Minecraft website do you go to change your password?