# Can't login to Technic Launcher

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-technic-pack

So, i'm trying to login to login to Technic Launcher for the first time on a pretty new PC, just a week after migrating my account and changing my name. It refuses to work. I have tried E-Mail, username, my old username, even older passwords. All combinations, and they refuse to work.

Comment: And what does it say?

Comment: welcome to stack exchange and ...all that. Someone may vote to close this, something to do with some crap about only supporting vanilla minecraft questions. So my advice would  be to reach out to the technic community through forums. Also google your issue and your operating system. Odds on, someone else, if not many others, have had this issue. So hopefully there exists some solution to this issue.

Comment: It's not a crash dump with a million lines of code about three hundred installed mods and no explanation of the problem.  It's an easily reproducible issue with a common launcher.  There's no call for closing here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Username and Password not recognized when logging into Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118282/username-and-password-not-recognized-when-logging-into-minecraft)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I had that problem, it was because I was using my old Minecraft username instead of my email address after creating a Mojang account and linking my Minecraft username to it.

Go log in at Minecraft.net.  If that works, use the exact same name/email and password to log in from the Technic Launcher.  If it doesn't work, hit that "Forgot Password" link and reset your password at minecraft.net.  Then use the new name/email and password at the Technic Launcher.

Comment: @Dragonix I have not heard anyone mention cookies anymore since around 2011.