# Mojang password not changing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted to play Minecraft again and tried to login but the password was wrong. I used the forgot password feature to change my password. the Mojang site says the password was successfully changed, but when I try to login I get the message incorret credentials. Please help!

Comment: Use the email address linked to your account, not the username

Comment: You may have incorrectly entered your new password, or, worst-case scenario, incorrectly set it. Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Username and Password not recognized when logging into Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118282/username-and-password-not-recognized-when-logging-into-minecraft)

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me, but I just left it for a few days and then it worked.

My advice would be to just let the password change go through.