# I can't sign into the windows minecraft launcher

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have tried to sign into Minecraft launcher using my account and two of my friends accounts. It does not work. The Minecraft login servers are up. I managed to log in once today, but it was an offline session, so I could not play on my server. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?

Yes, I have tried both Mojang and Minecraft accounts.
Yes, my internet is working.
Also, I never put in the wrong password.
Yes, I am using premium.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Premium?'

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. the premium version of minecraft, like I've paid for Minecraft

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Username and Password not recognized when logging into Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118282/username-and-password-not-recognized-when-logging-into-minecraft)

Answer (score 1):

Hello I had a similiar problem. And I solved it pretty easily. Just put the E-mail that you made the minecraft account into the username slot and the password that you specified and it hsould be OK.

And btw there is no premium minecraft it is a scam or you mean minecraft realms.