# What can I do when I get 'invalid username or password' in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't log in into Minecraft because it says 'invalid username or password'.

What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Username and Password not recognized when logging into Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118282/username-and-password-not-recognized-when-logging-into-minecraft)

Comment: I do wonder if there is a significant difference between "invalid username or password" and "the username and password are not recognized". Can it be ascribed to a difference in version, or are they fundamentally different errors?

Answer (score 0):

Since this obviously means that either you have no account or you remember one of your inputs wrong, or (god forbid) your account and the corresponding email have been hacked.

The only thing you can do to be sure, is to reset the password on your email account that is linked to you minecraft account and after that reset your minecraft acount password. If you however simply do not own any account you will to buy the game first and not just download it.

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://minecraft.net/ then attempt to log into the site using the upper right corner "Log in" link - the site uses the same login and password as the game. Use the "Forgot your password?" (between the password entry box and the "Log In" button) link to access the recovery options - resetting the password through email or contacting user support.