# How do I recover my minecraft account if my computer was wiped?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

My sister has a computer and we both had Minecraft on it. I still have Minecraft and I have a server that I asked her to join. Then I remembered that one day, her computer had randomly stopped working and she rebooted it to find that it had deleted everything off of her computer. I miss when we would play Minecraft together all the time and I can't find anything on the internet that doesn't talk about going into your files and recovering your account there. She can't do that. I would really like to help her get back on Minecraft but I cant without the internet's help.

Comment: Her Minecraft account wouldnt be saved locally on her machine, it would be saved on Mojangs servers. She should be able to log into their website with her credentials and then just redownload the game. Now all her saves will be gone, nothing you can do about that unless she had a backup service like OneDrive or something but Im assuming she didnt.

Comment: If you can still get in the game on the server, there is no reason to think she wouldn't be able to join you. Like Kyle Rone said, just let her log in to her account and install the game again, and join you on that server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Username and Password not recognized when logging into Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118282/username-and-password-not-recognized-when-logging-into-minecraft)

Comment: I smell an XY problem here ...

Answer (score 0):

If You Get The Minecraft Launcher On Your PC Then You Need To Log In To Your Minecraft Account Then It Should Be Done!