# Why can't I log into the old Minecraft: Java Edition launcher? Throws InvalidCredentialsExeption

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux, minecraft-launcher

I know for a fact that the information is right, but when I try to log in, it says: `InvalidCredentialsException: Invalid credentials. Invalid username or password.`

The launcher's version is `1.6.89-j` (the java version, the program executes a javabinary).

Also, if it helps, I am on Debian 8, 32-bit (I know I can't use the newer versions, I only want to run the older ones that support the 32-bit LWJGL).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Username and Password not recognized when logging into Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118282/username-and-password-not-recognized-when-logging-into-minecraft)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears either your username or your password (or possibly both!) are wrong...

Comment: I know, but these credentials work on [the website](https://minecraft.net)...

EDIT: no they don't! what happened, i'm sure i wrote the correct password!