# Signing in Minecraft Java edition: Mojang version

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I try to log in to Minecraft, I get the message "Invalid email or password". I have tried resetting my password multiple times, and I know that I have the right email. What should I do?

Comment: Did you switch to a Microsoft account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Username and Password not recognized when logging into Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118282/username-and-password-not-recognized-when-logging-into-minecraft)